# Are there any difference between windows NT and windows XP driver development?

Tags: windows, driver

I found [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/driverdev.aspx) on windows NT driver development,

but not sure whether it can be applied for windows XP without modification.

Anyone knows?

**UPDATE**

BTW, is it a MUST to use cdecl calling convention(`int _cdecl main`) to communicate with a driver?

Comment: By "Windows XP" mean WDM (old style), or KMDF/UMDF (new style)?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a huge difference.  I'm sure there are differences, but they will be documented on MSDN for whichever API you're interested in.

The big difference comes with Vista and [WDDM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480220.aspx).